# Meaning of !! javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I found some code about authentication with angular and i can't understand this trick :

```
authService.isAuthenticated = function () {
    return !!Session.userId;
};
```

What does `!!` mean 'different of userId' ?

whenever `true = !!true = !!!!true =>etc`, it don't understand this.

Somebody can help me?

(https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/techniques-for-authentication-in-angularjs-applications-7bbf0346acec for the source , part 'The AuthService')

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`!!` Converts any value to a `boolean` value

```
 > !!null
 false

 > !!true
 true

 > !!{}
 true

 > !!false
 false
```

If a value is `falsey` then the result will be `false`. If it is `truthy` the result will be `true`.

Even more, the third `!` inverts the converted value so the above examples become:

```
    > !!!null
    true

    > !!!true
    false

    > !!!{}
    false

    > !!!false
    true
```

Comment: You won't ever need three `!`. Just one or two :)

Comment: Yeah, but the OP was asking, so I just went to clarify the concept behind this :)

Comment: yeah, but it came out confusing. The concept here is that the second `!` negates the first negation, thus restoring value to its original state of truthiness, but now as real boolean (which is enforced by the first `!`)

Answer (score 2):

It forces what is returned to be a `boolean` and not an integer or empty value. For example, `0` evaluates to `false` with `==` but will not with `===`. So to be sure that any integer `0` returned will be converted into an boolean, we use `!!`. This also works if `null` or `undefined` is returned.

So whats happening is actually:

```
var test = null;
var result = !test; // returns true
    result = !return; // returns false
```

Answer (score 1):

!! is used to convert the value to the right of it to its equivalent boolean value.

```
!!false === false
!!true === true
```

Answer (score 0):

Coerces oObject to boolean. If it was falsey (e.g. 0, `null`, `undefined`, etc.), it will be `false`, otherwise, `true`.

```
!oObject  //Inverted boolean
!!oObject //Non inverted boolean so true boolean representation
```

So !! is not an operator, it's just the ! operator twice.

Referred from : https://stackoverflow.com/a/784946/2218635